# What is the architecture of a service like npm?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, architecture

I am thinking of building a service that stores code projects (similar to how I imagine the npm registry works).  The goal is just to archive multiple code projects and be able to run queries on them.  I am trying to decide on the an appropriate architecture for this project.  I am considering two options

Option 1: store the code in a file structure eg

```
project x
  |- ver 0.1
  |- ver 0.2
  |- ver 0.3
```

Option 2: store the code in a database table

```
| project name | code | version |
```

The issues I see with each option are

Option 1:

1. Ability to run queries on the file system e.g how to reference the file system to database records

Option 2:

1. Storing thousands of fairly large (up to 5MB) code bases in a database record
2. Storing code with multiple folders inside a database record

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Plan out what queries you need to run.  In doing so, you may realize things like "`grep` works better than `WHERE body LIKE '%x%'".  OTOH,`SELECTs` into the meta info may be easier with a db approach.  Also, consider a hybrid:  Only meta info is in the database; meanwhile the code is sitting in some tree structure on disk.

But do figure out more of the questions you will be asking.  And sketch out the code (both SQL vs filesystem) needed to execute each.

Comment: Agree with Rick. Can you give examples of the kind of queries you want this system to answer?